# How to change grub timeout to zero?

Tags: boot, grub2

I can not change this value, I establish zero but when you start your pc grub menu appears for 15 seconds until it self-select.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash intel_pstate=disable quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I do wrong?

```
$ lsb_release -r
Release:    14.10
```

Comment: Did you run the command `sudo update-grub` afterwards to apply and save the changes you made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is os-prober, the grub detect other system operative and canot start inmediately, disable it and works fine :)

Solution: http://foro.elhacker.net/gnulinux/no_puedo_establecer_el_timeout_del_grub-t438579.0.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you've edited the correct variables, but still need to update grub.

Try:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Does not works https://youtu.be/IOZGvZf9VZg